# How to send data from Windows to HID keyboard?

Tags: c#, keyboard, hid

I am trying for days to send data from Windows to my STM32F103C8T6 CustomHID keyboard with Visual Studio in c#.

I tried many libraries and stuffs that did not work. Like this one, which was the easiest to implement: http://www.florian-leitner.de/index.php/2007/08/03/hid-usb-driver-library/ after many tries, I found sending datas does not work for keyboard devices with this library.
At this state, the application is only capable to detect if the device is connected or not, sending data does not work.

Descriptor (79):

```
0x05, 0x01,                    // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
0x09, 0x06,                    // USAGE (Keyboard)
0xa1, 0x01,                    // COLLECTION (Application)
0x05, 0x07,                    //   USAGE_PAGE (Keyboard)
0x19, 0xe0,                    //   USAGE_MINIMUM (Keyboard LeftControl)
0x29, 0xe7,                    //   USAGE_MAXIMUM (Keyboard Right GUI)
0x15, 0x00,                    //   LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
0x25, 0x01,                    //   LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1)
0x75, 0x01,                    //   REPORT_SIZE (1)
0x95, 0x08,                    //   REPORT_COUNT (8)
0x81, 0x02,                    //   INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
0x95, 0x01,                    //   REPORT_COUNT (1)
0x75, 0x08,                    //   REPORT_SIZE (8)
0x81, 0x03,                    //   INPUT (Cnst,Var,Abs)
0x95, 0x05,                    //   REPORT_COUNT (5)
0x75, 0x01,                    //   REPORT_SIZE (1)
0x05, 0x08,                    //   USAGE_PAGE (LEDs)
0x19, 0x01,                    //   USAGE_MINIMUM (Num Lock)
0x29, 0x05,                    //   USAGE_MAXIMUM (Kana)
0x91, 0x02,                    //   OUTPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
0x95, 0x01,                    //   REPORT_COUNT (1)
0x75, 0x03,                    //   REPORT_SIZE (3)
0x91, 0x03,                    //   OUTPUT (Cnst,Var,Abs)
0x95, 0x06,                    //   REPORT_COUNT (6)
0x75, 0x08,                    //   REPORT_SIZE (8)
0x15, 0x00,                    //   LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
0x25, 0x65,                    //   LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (101)
0x05, 0x07,                    //   USAGE_PAGE (Keyboard)
0x19, 0x00,                    //   USAGE_MINIMUM (Reserved (no event indicated))
0x29, 0x65,                    //   USAGE_MAXIMUM (Keyboard Application)
0x81, 0x00,                    //   INPUT (Data,Ary,Abs)
0x06, 0x00, 0xff,              // USAGE_PAGE (Vendor Defined Page 1)
0x09, 0x01,                    // USAGE (Vendor Usage 1)
0x15, 0x00,                    // LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
0x26, 0xff, 0x00,              // LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (255)
0x75, 0x08,                    // REPORT_SIZE (8)
0x95, 0x04,                    // REPORT_COUNT (4)
0x91, 0x02,                    //   OUTPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
0xc0                           // END_COLLECTION
```

Part of the code that handles the receiving part:

```
static int8_t CUSTOM_HID_OutEvent_FS(uint8_t *buffer)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
    if(buffer[1] == 0x01 || buffer[1] == 1 || buffer[1] == '1' || buffer[2] == 0x01 || buffer[2] == 1 || buffer[2] == '1')
    {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_13, 1);
    }
 
  return (USBD_OK);
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
```

Visual Studio part with USBHIDDRIVER.dll (Florian's library):

```
USBHIDDRIVER.USBInterface usb = new USBInterface("vid_0483", "pid_5750");
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (usb.Connect())
                MessageBox.Show("Connecté!");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Deconnecté");
        }
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          
            byte[] Buffer = new byte[64];
            for(int i = 0; i>=64; i++)
            {
                Buffer[i] = 1;
            }

            usb.write(Buffer);
        }
```

Thank's for you help considering I am a beginner!

Comment: I think ```for(int i = 0; i>=64; i++)``` should be ```for(int i = 0; i<64; i++)```.  The condition in a for statement means "while", not "until" ... so your buffer is not being initialized as you intended.

Comment: Thank you for your help. You are right, just made a little error, but this does not fix the problem, I tried so many ways to send data through the "button1_Click" function, this for loop was just to make you understand I want to send data this size.

Comment: Ok, I would install Wireshark and capture the USB traffic to see exactly what is being sent to the device. If your extra data is being sent then the issue must be at the device end

Comment: I just read that Windows blocks HID communication with keyboards and mice.

Comment: At this state, I don't know how to send data...  I think using the serial COM port is not the good way considering we need to select the device.

Comment: I am aslo wondering how Logitech, Corsair... do to send data from PC to HID keyboards, mice.